# MacOS Python 3 netrc operations end up with UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, .netrc

On MacOS (Mojave, same on High Sierra) with Python 3, after installing and using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for some time, seemingly all operations that use a network connection return a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

So far I've tried using various versions of Python 3 (3.6.Xs, 3.7 tried), system provided python, uninstalling pyenv and reinstalling Python3 with brew, setting locale in `~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile` to `en_US.UTF-8`, running commands with prefixed `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` or `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`.

The issue still presents when used with different Python 3 distributions (tried Anaconda, brew).

Returning to MacOs's python 2 fixed similar issue with python2 stack.

Examples (all issues present with different python3 distributions):

Using pip3 (pyenv 3.7)

```
pip3 install requests
Collecting requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 484, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 442, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 587, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 705, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 814, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 397, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 309, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 540, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 161, in __call__
    netrc_auth = get_netrc_auth(req.url)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 195, in get_netrc_auth
    _netrc = netrc(netrc_path).authenticators(host)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/netrc.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._parse(file, fp, default_netrc)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/netrc.py", line 39, in _parse
    toplevel = tt = lexer.get_token()
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
  File "/Users/nikolaj/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 104: invalid continuation byte
```

Decoding responses to standard requests (on Anaconda)

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get("http://www.google.pl")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    auth = get_netrc_auth(request.url)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 203, in get_netrc_auth
    _netrc = netrc(netrc_path).authenticators(host)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/netrc.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._parse(file, fp, default_netrc)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/netrc.py", line 39, in _parse
    toplevel = tt = lexer.get_token()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 104: invalid continuation byte
```

My locale configuration

```
locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your `~/.netrc` file to contain UTF-8-clean data. Currently it does not.

See the [`.netrc` file documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) on what the file should contain.

The problem doesn't arise on Python 2, because there the file is not opened as Unicode text (Python 2 mostly operates in a binary data world).